# EasyMock calling two DAO methods- Unexpected method call UserAdminDAO.updateUser

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

In my unit test for DAO method, I am trying to test the update user method. But, I have to create an user and then update it.  So my mock DAO is expecting the addUser call, but then when I am, calling the update method it is complaining

java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call UserAdminDAO.updateUser(null):

here is the code snipper

```
expect(userAdminDAO.addNewUser(u1)).andReturn(u1);
    replay(userAdminDAO);

    User u2 = (User)userService.addNewUser(ar);
    Assert.assertEquals(u.getUserName(), u2.getUserName());

    u2.setUserName("new modified");
userAdminDAO.updateUser(u2);   //error is on this line 
    expectLastCall().once().andAnswer(new IAnswer<User>() {
        public User answer() {
            return null;
        }
    });
    replay(userAdminDAO);
    userService.updateUser(u2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've replayed the mock before adding the second expectation:

```
expect(userAdminDAO.addNewUser(u1)).andReturn(u1);
replay(userAdminDAO); // you shouldn't do this
...
userAdminDAO.updateUser(u2);
```